# while loop code not executing squentically in node js

Tags: node.js

Trying to execute code in while loop and set flag, but there unable to set flag, its carries the initial flag value.My code is like :

```
var flag = 0
while(!flag)
{
    connection.query('SELECT nlc,id,user_id FROM tbl_buy WHERE `type`="buy" AND `status`="available" AND coin_id="'+jsondata.coinid+'" AND order_type="market" order by id ASC LIMIT '+offset+',1',function (error,results, fields)
    { 
        if(results.length > 0)
        {
            flag = 1; // want to set flag when i recieve the result 
            connection.query('SELECT tbl_buy.* from (select tbl_buy.*, (@sum := @sum + nlc) as cume_stock from tbl_buy cross join (select @sum := 0) params  WHERE tbl_buy.type="sell" AND tbl_buy.status="available" AND tbl_buy.user_id!="'+results[0].user_id+'" AND tbl_buy.coin_id="'+jsondata.coinid+'" AND tbl_buy.order_type="market" order by id ) tbl_buy where cume_stock-nlc < "'+results[0].nlc+'"',function (error,results_arr, fields)
            {
                res.end(JSON.stringify(results_arr));
                myCallback(results,results_arr);
            });
        }
    });
    console.log('flag value :  '+flag); // this line executes first and then the query is been executed , here the value remains same (ie flag = 0 and not changed to 1)
    offset++;
}
```

**Not getting why the control goes to the console.log('flag value :  '+flag); instead of executing sequentially**

Comment: `results` really has length > 0? Do you have check that?

Comment: The callback function you pass as the second argument to `connection.query()` is executed when the query completes. The query is executed asynchronously, the code that calls `connection.query()` does not wait for it to complete. This means the callback function runs some time in the future, **after** the `while` loop completes.

Comment: so, to solve this issue i tried using async and used waterfall structure of async like:

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.query
```

is an asynchronous call, so

```
console.log('flag value :  '+flag);
```

is executed immediately, and the callback doesn't get executed until the database is finished (it could take a while).

If you want it to execute after the query is finished, put it with myCallback

Research the term asynchronous

Edit:

It looks like you are trying to repeatedly call the query.  I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
var secondQuery = function(results) {
    connection.query('SELECT tbl_buy.* from (select tbl_buy.*, (@sum := @sum + nlc) as cume_stock from tbl_buy cross join (select @sum := 0) params  WHERE tbl_buy.type="sell" AND tbl_buy.status="available" AND tbl_buy.user_id!="'+results[0].user_id+'" AND tbl_buy.coin_id="'+jsondata.coinid+'" AND tbl_buy.order_type="market" order by id ) tbl_buy where cume_stock-nlc < "'+results[0].nlc+'"',function (error,results_arr, fields) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify(results_arr));
        myCallback(results,results_arr);
    });
}

var database_poll_timeout = 10; // you can try setting to 0 if you want

var firstQuery = function() {
    connection.query('SELECT nlc,id,user_id FROM tbl_buy WHERE `type`="buy" AND `status`="available" AND coin_id="'+jsondata.coinid+'" AND order_type="market" order by id ASC LIMIT '+offset+',1', function(error,results, fields) { 
        if(results.length > 0) {
            secondQuery(results);
        } else {
            // this is your while loop - wait for the database to return before retrying
            setTimeout(firstQuery, database_poll_timeout);
        }
    });
}

firstQuery();
```

Comment: Now, i put all code of while loop in the myCallback function, but still it is executing infinite times

Answer (score 0):

Because node is asynchronous. That's why when your query blocking processing it pushed your code into `event-loop` and execute next statement in you case `console.log('flag value :  '+flag);`